# Multiple points for same y-value

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: image for reference]

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv("Counsumer_Price_Index.csv")


sav <- df %>%
  filter(ï..Location %in% c("IRL", "CAN", "AUS",
                            "USA", "FRA", "DEU",
                            "ESP", "ITA")) %>%
  filter(Time == 2021) %>%
  filter(Subject != "Energy")
sav


sav %>% ggplot(aes(x = Percentage, y = ï..Location)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Subject), size = 2.5) + 
  geom_segment(aes(yend = ï..Location, colour = Subject), xend = 0 , linetype="dotted") + theme_light()
```

I want to make a lollipop plot for the CPI index data, for each country there are three categories how do I display the categories such that they dont overlap

I want to make a lollipop plot for the CPI index data, for each country there are three categories how do I display the categories such that they dont overlap

Comment: Could you provide the output of `dput(sav)`?

Comment: Sure, here -> https://pastebin.com/GZWxCKdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position_dodge` with a `coord_flip`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

sav %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ï..Location, y = Percentage, colour = Subject)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5, position = position_dodge(0.5)) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = Percentage),
               linetype = "dotted", position = position_dodge(0.5)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

sav %>% ggplot(aes(x = Percentage, y = ï..Location)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Subject), size = 2.5) + 
  geom_segment(aes(yend = ï..Location, colour = Subject), xend = 0 , linetype="dotted") + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ Subject) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]